# What steps/processes would you need to take to create an API

Tags: php, api, oop, web-applications, social-networking

What steps/processes will I need to take to plan the creation of an API for my website (that uses PHP and SQL technology)? Also, what information will I need to know?

For an example, Step 1: Create index page, Step 2: Create this set of or library code, etc...

I am creating a social networking site from scratch that I would like to implement a API with during the alpha phase. I assume I will need to make the application object oriented which I have no problem doing. But where exactly do you start in the API implementation process?

Comment: May I suggest building and launching the site first, before you worry about an API.

Comment: An API is just an an Application Programming Interface, you can make it however you want it as long as you can interface with it.

Comment: there are hundreds of tuts out there in the google.

Comment: @Amber: So, I can just create the site first (which would include object oriented programming), and then create the API last???

Comment: @user Have you thought through what an API *is*? It's just a slightly different, standardized, machine-readable way to access the same data you make available through your website. Instead of HTML you serve up XML or JSON on a slightly different URL. That's really all there is to it on a basic level. Yes, you can add that at any time later.

Comment: Create your site as a usual site. Then implement API. API is not a spicific form of Application, it's only a way to access your Application methods/functions from outside not using UI.

Comment: @webbandit: Right! I want to know the steps to do that. Because I would like to eventually do that for my product.

Comment: Why downvote, Sounds like an interesting question. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very first of all: decide why you really need this API. If you're going to produce some client app that uses this API itself, that's a good reason. If you're just hoping that somebody will use that API to do interesting things once your service hopefully becomes popular, that's a bad reason. You'll just be spending a long time working on the API without anybody ever wanting to use it. Make your service popular and gauge the interest in an API first.

Having said that, an API is just yet another URL on your site where you serve up data in structured, machine readable XML or JSON (or another format), it is not fundamentally anything different from an HTML document served up for your regular pages.
The main difference is that the API needs to be well designed and *stable*. You can redesign your HTML anytime on a whim, but once a client is written to use your API, it should not change for some time to come. So you'll need to plan the usage and data format of the API well. This is easier if you have a good idea what it will be used for. Study existing APIs of other large services in detail to see how they solved some of the details.

Internally you will want to structure your application modularly. Properly separate concerns using, for instance, the MVC pattern. You will have your core logic in your Models and you will have *two* (or more) Views; one regular HTML view and a JSON/XML API view for largely the same data. That means: don't mix any important logic with your HTML which you'd have to duplicate in your API views.

Comment: Ok, I like your response. Very useful. When I am creating my html, I will have to do things like create OOP PHP code to manage log ins and dynamic content, etc. But is there certain FYIs I need to know on how to program/write the HTML/PHP/MySQL code? Basically, I am asking can I just code my HTML and PHP Object Oriented code anyway I feel as a programmer, or do I have to keep in mind the API I will be creating later? I don't know if I making sense here. haha.

Comment: Also, the social network will be a network of sites. I am going to also create phone apps and allow the application to be useful with other applications as well. I expect it to be a site with a large amount of users.

Comment: That depends on how you usually feel. As I said, since you'll want to avoid basically rewriting a complete second version of your app for the API, structure the internals in a way that they can be reused in various contexts later. Don't hardcode any part of it expecting it to be used in a web-HTML context only (except for the HTML views, obviously). Beyond that this is too broad to give more specific advice.

Answer (score 1):

For PHP try http://laravel.com/ - https://tutsplus.com/lesson/restful-controllers/ for a tutorial. There was a good nettuts video about using laravel for a backbonejs backend, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Thanks chovy! It's a great help

Comment: I found the video: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/understanding-backbone-js-and-the-server/

Answer (score 1):

You can also try a backend-as-a-service provider to automatically generate a rest interface for your datamodel. E.g. [www.apiomat.com](http://www.apiomat.com) provides generated php-client code to access the generated REST interface.

Comment: Well, I could be nuts, but... I want to design EVERYTHING from scratch. Code, Graphics, and ALL.